# Gtalk audio notifications with the application in focus

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-talk

I have recently upgraded my Orange UK Samsung i9100p to ICS and have been having trouble with audio notifications for new gtalk messages. It seems it notifies you while you are in conversation with someone, obviously I don't need notifying when I can see the text appearing in front of me, so while I'm talking I will get constant unnecessary pings when I receive a reply. I don't remember this being the case for the gingerbread version, has anyone noticed this change? And found a method or app to sort out the notifications?

Comment: I have the same problem on my new Samsung S3 with ICS. Really annoying.